# How do I parse through a CSV (comma separated file) and display output

Tags: java, arrays, csv

Does anyone know how I would go about creating an application that will go through a comma separated file (CSV) and organize that information and subsequently put that into a database? For example, I have to go through a file that looks like this:

```
Name of Athlete, Birthday, Salary($)
John Morris, 9/25/1991, 5000000 
Mike Hawk, 2/2/1988, 1000000
Dewayne Johnson, 11/22/1985, 4000000
```

etc.

How would I organize this information and set it up? I am trying to make it so I can ask the user for input. For example: have the user enter "a" for amount of salary and output all the players who make that EXACT amount of money.

Player 1 name, Player 1 birthday Player 2 name, Player 2 birthday

Any help is appreciated. I would appreciated help with reading the information and storing/retrieving it.

Don't give me the complete answer. I am a student learning this and I want to understand it.

Comment: Since you want to learn, what are your own thoughts on how this could be achieved? Think about what defines a CSV file, and what standard java library classes can you use to read a file?

Comment: Your second line had two complete entries, so I edited it to two lines. If that wasn't your intention (then your question is a little unclear) you can revert the edit.

Comment: This is quite a broad question, a little OT. I recommend you do some research on the __many__ aspects involved in trying to do what you describe. I assume you're using java. Start with the basics: how to read input, how to read a file, how to read a CSV (you might need a library for that), how to write/read from/to a DB, etc. Then write code, test it and come back to SO with specific questions about your code. Good luck!

Comment: The point is to be able to parse through a plain text file, and find the necessary values and store in arrays

Answer (score 1):

I would think about these steps:

- Create a class to map with the data in your CSV. For example, an `Athlete` class with attributes `name`, `birthday` and `salary` (it's up to you define each data type).
- Read the CSV file. You can use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) (using a [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)) to accomplish this.
- For each line read:

  - Split the string into several strings by comma (,)
  - Create a new `Athlete` object and parse each string into an attribute to set it into the object.
  - Store the new `Athlete` in a collection (`List` or something).
- Once you completed loading a number of `Athlete`s, save them into your database.
- Repeat this until you finish reading the csv.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting by a comma is a naive way of dealing with CSV. Unless you are 100% sure you will never have a comma in an actual field, then go this route, but if you may ever encounter a string like `hello, my name is devshorts`, you should use a CSV library. http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ seems to be a good choice.

Once thats done, map each entry to a class that represents what a line is. Make an `Atheltes` class, where it has fields for `Name`, `Birthdate`, and `Salary`.

You can use a direct JDBC connection to a sqlite/mysql/whatever database and insert (using raw SQL) the values into a table called `Atheletes`.  If you want to use an ORM go with hibernate, but that may be more work than you need to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple way of reading this type of files would be using a BufferedReader that allows you to read the file line by line.

Then use split function to separate the string by delimiter and convert it into an array.

With the resulting array you can insert data into the database making proper conversion as required.

Comment: This is not feasible for csv files that contain quoted string values, because they may contain the delimiter character.

Comment: It can be adjusted by using quotes as part of the delimiter like ','